# Jquery Builder?

Tags: jquery, builder

If you take a look at:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ as an example, there are tons of options to set AND almost always I get a { or a ) messed up. Is there some sort of jquery builder available? In other words you might have a drop down for a function and below that a drop down for each parameter and the choices for each?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Some IDE's have a thing called Snippets that allow you to create a custom template that you can type in parameters for. However, you still have to create the template and type in those parameters, you could mess stuff up there too.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Visual Studio you can enable jQuery Intellisense, take a look at this [article](http://www.stefanprodan.eu/2011/05/improve-visual-studio-2010-jscript-editor-with-jquery-intellisense-and-code-outlining/).